# Finding which soft locked states do not have active flow sessions

Tags: corda

In one of our Corda databases, we have a set of soft-locked states, despite all flow sessions being completed. It is easy to simply set all of these to null in a dev environment. However, in production, this would be very dangerous whilst the node is processing flows. So, I'm wondering if I can get a list of active StateMachine ids and correlating these with the soft-lock ids in VAULT_STATES. Unfortunately, the NODE_CHECKPOINTS doesn have this id as a field.

Is there a way of getting a list of active StateMachine ids?

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing the node via RPC, you can use stateMachinesFeed. This returns a data feed of currently in-progress state machine infos and an observable of future state machine adds/removes.

Internally, you would have to do something quick hacky which is something like:

```
private val stateMachineManager = serviceHub.getFieldValue("flowStarter")!!.getFieldValue("smm")!! as StateMachineManager
```

You can then call something like track() on the StateMachineManager.

Comment: thanks. wrote this: https://gist.github.com/dazraf/74a9e9bd93d55a250ed904b27e51b949